# PHP calculate a dropdown input to a total

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, echo

I have a plugin, that does his job wel. I only need an extra option.
The form echoes a total price. I need to add a shipping cost to the total price depending on a choice in a dropdown menu.
Below is the dropdownlist, and in the  tags is the output of the total price, depending on the product(s) that are been selected.
Ik hope someone can help.

```
<table>
<select name="shipper">
<option value="25">Netherlands</option>
<option value="49">Europe</option>
</select>

<td><strong>
  <?php 
    echo $this->output_currency(
      $totalPrice + $totalShipping + $shipper, 
      $currencySymbol, 
      $decimalPoint, 
      $thousandsSeperator) 
  ?></strong></td>
</table>
```

I have tried all the solutions below but none of them works. The version of Tim shows the totalprice and the selection for shipping but doesn't add the two. Another one gives an NaN. Maybe you need more code, because the echo code belongs to a shopping cart plugin with a bunch more code.

Comment: to do this you can make ajax cal on select and retrieve price

Comment: You might want to have a look at JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jQuery for that - everytime that "select[name=shipper]" changes, update your price. You may have an unvisible value of the cost but the shipping and just update it with jQuery, like that:

```
<script>
    $("select[name=shipper]").change(function() {
        var value=$(this).val();
        var cost = $("input[name=cost]").val();
        document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = cost+value;
    }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="cost" value="<?php your_cost(); ?>" />
<select name="shipper">
    <option value="25">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="49">Europe</option>
</select>

<td><strong id="cost"></strong></td>
```

Comment: `var value=$(this).val();` shouldn't work because you need to get the val of the selected `option` not the select box itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
   <select name="shipper">
      <option value="25" data-cost="1.99">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="49" data-cost="5.99">Europe</option>
   </select>
```

//Include jquery library here

```
<script>
   var totalPrice = '<?php echo $totalPrice; ?>';
   var totalShipping = '<?php echo $totalShipping; ?>';
   var shipper = '<?php echo $shipper; ?>';
   var currencySymbol = '<?php echo $currencySymbol; ?>';  
   var decimalPoint = '<?php echo $decimalPoint; ?>';
   var thousandsSeperator = '<?php echo $thousandsSeperator; ?>';

   $(function(){
      $('select[name=shipper]').change(function(){
         var shipping_append = $(this).children('option:selected').data('cost');
         totalShipping += shipping_append;
         var text_string = ((totalPrice*1) + (totalShipping*1))
                           + ' ' + shipper + ' ' + currencySymbol + decimalPoint + thousandsSeperator.

         $('#output').text(text_string);
      });
   });
</script>

<td id="output"><strong>
  <?php 
    echo $this->output_currency(
      $totalPrice + $totalShipping + $shipper, 
      $currencySymbol, 
      $decimalPoint, 
      $thousandsSeperator) 
  ?></strong></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Tim Joyce,I have tried to use your code but it doesn't add the shipping choice to the total price.

Comment: It won't append the price to any php code you have since this is a javascript code. You will need to send the output back to a server side page for processing.

Comment: Thanks Tim, any thoughts of how i can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Method with JQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.calTotal = function()
            {
                var shipper = $('#shipper').val();
                $.get('http://localhost/ajax/calTotal.php?shipper='+shipper, function(data) {
                    $('#cost').html(data);              
                });
            }

            $("#shipper").change($.calTotal);
            $.calTotal(); //Calling calTotal Method to get Amount for default shipper
        });
    </script>

    <table>
    <select id="shipper" name="shipper">
        <option value="25">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="49">Europe</option>
    </select>   

    <td><strong>
    <span id='cost'></span>
    </strong></td>
    </table>
```

PHP file (http://localhost/ajax/calTotal.php)

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['shipper'])){
        $shipper_cost = $this->getShippingCost($_GET['shipper']);   
        echo $this->output_currency(
            $totalPrice + $totalShipping + $shipper_cost, 
            $currencySymbol, 
            $decimalPoint, 
            $thousandsSeperator
        );
    }else{
        echo 'Please select shipper';
    }
?>
```

you have to define getShippingCost() method to get shipper cost from database.

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed playing arround with the old code i made. And could not find what was wrong with it, but i have posted a total type of script now. "Remember you have to have the jquery-1.8.2 java library included like:

```
<?
$totalPrice = '100';
$totalShipping = '100';
$currencySymbol = '100';
$decimalPoint = '100';
$thousandsSeperator = '100';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inset the link til the jquery 1.8.2 javascript file here." ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculate').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
               if(value != 0) {
                 total += parseFloat(value);
            }
        });
        total = total + parseFloat(<?php echo $totalPrice; ?>);
        total = total + parseFloat(<?php echo $totalShipping; ?>);
        total = total + parseFloat(<?php echo $currencySymbol; ?>);
        total = total + parseFloat(<?php echo $decimalPoint; ?>);
        total = total + parseFloat(<?php echo $thousandsSeperator; ?>);
        $('#total').text('' + total.toFixed(0));
    });
});
</script>

<select class="calculate" name="shipper">
<option value="25">Netherlands</option>
<option value="49">Europe</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id="total"></span>
```

You can decide the data of the strings yourself in the top of the file. But this one is testet and are working on a apache server with the latest updates of php5 and apache.

Comment: Hi Coookkiiee, i hace tried this solution but the outcome is NaN.

Comment: I'll just run a test on it and see the outcome. I'll comment on the results for you.

Comment: I made a few changes, not anything special, but read my entire post again, i have writen what you have to do.